# If "par" ≠ quelque ("some"), then how can parfois ≅ quelquefois = sometimes?

Tags: étymologie

Unquestionably, **par** doesn't necessarily mean ***quelque***. For example, you can't replace **par** with ***quelque*** in [en ***quelque***  sorte, ***quelque***  peu, ***quelque***  temps, ***quelque***'un](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque#D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9s).

But then why does **par**fois = ***quelque***fois?  [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parfois) doesn't expound the etymology.

> **Étymol. et Hist.** Fin xiiies. *par fois* [ms. 2emoitié du xives.] «de temps à autre; par moments» (Mahieu Le Vilain, *Les Metheores d'Aristote*, éd. R. Edgren, 129, 16), attest. isolée, à nouv. ds Ph. De Commynes, *Mémoires*, éd. J. Calmette, t.2, p.330; 1530 *parfoys* (Palsgr., p.811). Comp. de _par_1* et de *fois**.

Answer (score 2):

The TLF doesn't make a semantic link between *par* and *quelque*, all it says is that *quelquefois*/*des fois*  can be synonyms of *parfois*, which does not mean that *quelque* or *des*  could have some sort of semantic relationship to *par*. When we look at the meaning of words in the 21st c., and specially where words are the result of very old agglutination, the meaning of each basic element has often been lost over centuries of evolution of the language.

If we had to link *par* and *quelque* we might find it on the ground that they can both refer to repetition, *par* by its etymology and *quelque* by its meaning if we accept the fact that when you have a certain quantity of something it means you have more than one, therefore the repetition of this something<sup>1</sup>.

***Parfois*** (1530, *parfoys*)

> est le résultat de la soudure de la locution adverbiale *par fois* « de temps en temps ». Celle-ci est formée de *par* exprimant une répétion dans le temps, et de *fois*. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey)

La préposition ***par*** (d'abord *per* 842) puis *par* (1050) est issue de la préposition latine *per* qui avait un sens spatial et un sens temporel.
C'est ce dernier que l'on retrouve dans *parfois* : « pendant, durant; exprimant la répétition dans le temps ». ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par))

***Quelquefois*** est le résultat de la soudure de *quelque fois*,  a d'abord eu le sens d'« une fois, une certaine fois », et a pris la valeur de « parfois, de temps en temps » au XVI<sup>e</sup> s. ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quelquefois)).
*Quelque* est employé comme indéfini avec une valeur d'indétermination quant à la quantité depuis le XII<sup>e</sup> s. (Réf. *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>.  A reasoning I can make for a countable noun like *fois* but I would not make when *quelque* is used with an uncountable noun.</sup>